# On my local network what can't I ping xyz but I can ping xyz.local on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns, lan, ping

On my local network machine xyz has the IP of 192.168.1.95. If I ping xyz.local it resolves properly. If I ping xyz I get "Temporary failure in name resolution". I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and am pinging a Raspian machine with the Avahi daemon running. If I use a Windows machine I can add the domain suffix of .local and it will work. Is there something analogous in Ubuntu for this? What is going on with the DNS name resolution here?

Comment: Read `man systemd-resolve` ( `http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/systemd-resolve.1.html`) and the `man` pages in the "See also" section of the `man` page.

Comment: See launchpad bugs 1624071,1647031, 1727237,1805027      I have added  libnss-resolve to my 20.04, but must admit every few months, the single name resolution stops working for a few months.  Adding the .local always seems to work.

Comment: Do you have `avahi-daemon` installed? Do you see your box in `avahi-discover` ?